# Post multiple files by List<HttpPostedFileBase>

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, file, upload

I just want to post my multiple files to controller via model.

```
class myModel{
    public List<string> contexts {get;set;}
    public List<HttpPostedFileBase> images {get;set;}
}
```

And there is Html

```
<input id="myImages" type=file multiple="multiple>
```

User add files to input tag and text inputs creating dynamically based on files count

```
<input id="text0"></input>
<input id="text1"></input>
<input id="text3"></input>
           ...
           .
```

After user fill the text inputs. hit the save button.
and I want to pass these datas to my controller via my model. 
I try form data but I couldn't be success

there is my trying

```
<script>
    function someFunction(){
        var data = new FormData();
        for (i = 0; i < $("#myImages")[0].files.length; i++) {
            data.append("images[]", $("#myImages")[0].files[i]);
            data.append("contexts[]", $("#text" + i).val());
        }
        $.ajax
        ({
            url: "/Admin/CreateGallery",
            type: "POST",
            data: data,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            success:function(){
                alert("very well");
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

I can get contexts but images list always null

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just changing this.

```
data.append("images[]", $("#myImages")[0].files[i]);
```

to this

```
data.append("images", $("#myImages")[0].files[i]);
```